# With jQuery, how can I implement a "page loading" animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I submit a form using jQuery, I want to display an animation image (`load.gif` or `progressbar.gif`, etc.) for a few seconds.

How can I show a GIF image in jQuery?