# BlockUI alternatives for IE9 beta?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

[BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) is throwing some exception when using its demos on IE9 beta.

Meanwhile, does anyone know a similar feature in jQuery for showing a "Please wait" message when ASP.NET AJAX is processing?

Comment: Honest question: why are you changing *your* code for someone else's beta bug? It's a beta, it's buggy, the user signed up for it when they installed IE9 beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation) using jQuery + Css.

When user click on a button, a please wait div appears and it's working also in IE9.