# Preload a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, dreamweaver

I'm looking to preload a website. I only want a loading bar once on the site. When its loading I want every page to pre load. How would I do this?

http://frankadvertisingus.com/fa_website/home.html

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Many studies have shown that users get bored and leave sites very very quickly – optimising the first load is worth doing, and this really goes against this. I understand that you need images for the transitions etc, but perhaps load them in the background once the bare minimum to show the site is available.

Comment: I would like it to load it all up front.

Comment: You can try this http://www.chillipear.com/plugins/preloader/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Right Click for Source code can be helpful

Here is the source where you can find the jQuery for it.
[http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/](https://web.archive.org/web/20110511045013/http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/)

Comment: Thats what I used but i want it to load the entire site not just that one page do i need to import the other files because I tried and that didn't work??? <script src="profile/about/about.html"></script>
    <script src="profile/people/people.html"></script>
    <script src="profile/awards/awards.html"></script>
    <script src="portfolio/overview/overview.html"></script>

Answer (score 0):

you could replace or hide the body while it is loading and showing that the page loads and when its done the content is displayed

there was an older post here about this:
[How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation)

should be that what you want

an html file for script ?  think its just working with .js

well you have to add it on every page using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="preload.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I only what it to load once...

Comment: well normally the browser caches a website so after the first visit it is loaded faster than at the first fisit so the user should see the preloafd animation just once

aditionally you cold create a cookie that will be created at the first visit and so when the user visits your website at the next time, the script doesnt load when there is the cookie 

but you think wrong, because there woul be generally just once the preloader due the caching of the browser, hope you understand

Comment: well, first i would check if the user sees the preloader just once normally, creating a cookie with php isnt so hard

Comment: it doesnt work <head>   <script language="php">  

<?php 
 $Month = 2592000 + time(); 
 //this adds 30 days to the current time 
 setcookie(AboutVisit, date("F jS - g:i a"), $Month);
 ?> 
 </script>

</head>

Comment: <script language="php"> is totally false, something like this doesnt exist  its <?php and has to be on the first line before your html code for creating a cookie so its in the very first line: <?php setcookie (); ?> ... line2: <html> line3: <head> ...  your question about how to preload a website should be already marked as done by you. The how, how you do it best or what the best solution is for it is another question, and i would test it (1st visit, browser caches website, no more preload animation), so you have normally not to do it with a cookie, it just works fine (normally)

Answer (score 0):

Header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function hideLoadingLayer(){
 document.getElementById("loading_layer").style.visibility="hidden";
 }
 </script>
```

Body

```
<body onload="hideLoadingLayer();">
```

Div

```
<div id="loading_layer"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" width="550" height="400" border="0" /></div>
```

CSS

```
#loading_layer{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:999999;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Inserted from [JavaScript (website) Web page preloader](http://ajwebdesigner.in/blog/javascript-website-web-page-preloader/)

Comment: you should always provide the content of external links, otherwise your answer is worthless when the link breaks. I've done this for you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Ok, this question is old, and link provided is dead, and some users provide nice correction on how to make usable answer, I decided to edit my answer explaining the process behind preloading instead providing just a link.

Preloading webpage is simply displaying some text, image or something else while the page is rendering, to notify the visitors that something is happening in the background. Easiest way is to include jQuery which simplify the whole process. Our main goal is to display, let say text, while page is loading. So, our task is displaying text first, then when the page is fully loaded, hide text and display content.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> // include jQuery source

 <script>
    $('.content').hide(); // hide content while rendering
    $(document).ready(function(){ // When page is fully loaded...
      $('.preload').hide(); // hide preloader
      $('.content').show(); // and show content
 });
<div class="preload">Loading...</div>
<div class="content">Some generic content here</div>
```

This is just basic example, and you can play with jQuery to make some nice preloaders.

**ORIGINAL**

This is my first preloader. It's very simple. While page is loading, it shows preloader, and then hide preloader and show page.
[Preload web site using jquery (simple)](http://www.golubovic.iz.rs/2012/11/preload-web-site-using-jquery/)

Comment: You can insert preload image to be more interesting for users. Just replace Loading text with image and thats it.