# Image servlet file delivery completion event

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

Suppose there is a 4.3 mb png file.I used Balus c Image servlet to show the image inline in my jsp page.But the file being 4.3mb in size takes time to download.I would like to show a loading gif in the meantime and keep the image hidden by setting its style as "display:none;".The question is how do i know that the image has been delivered completely by the servlet before  rendering the image.

Comment: In the code have you used any Input or OutPutstream because with the help of the stream you can verify that the image is loaded or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery "Please Waiting, Loading..." animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation)

Comment: response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
    stream.write(new ImageResizerUtil().resizeImageAsJPG(data,500));
    stream.flush(); 
    stream.close();

Comment: @jigar yes somewhat like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the url of your gif image in the html produced by the jsp, then fetch the image at load time:

```
$(function() {
    var loadr = new Image();
    $(loadr).load(function() {
        $("#myimg").attr("src", this.src);
    });
    loadr.src = "servletUrl";
});
```