# Jquery Dialog , showing animated gif when ajax fetching

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm loading a dialog box using an ajax call. I'd like to add an
animated gif to the dialog while the ajax fetch is running, and have
it go away when the fetch is complete.

My main functions which set and open dialog are as follows

```
    function showDetail(sipId) {
    ShowWOrderRows(sipId);
    $("#Container").data('title.dialog', 'Details of Order ' + sipId); 
    $("#Container").dialog("open");
    return false;
    }
$(function () {    
            $("#Container").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 300,
                width: 650
            });    
        });
```

and on **ShowWOrderRows** function I am fetching data with `$.ajax({ //some options  });`

and filling that data to `$('#Container')`.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery "Please Wait, Loading..." animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<img src="your gif" />').appendTo("#Container");

$.ajax({
  url: .....
  context: .....
  success: function(data){
    $("#Container").find('img').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Adam Right The only thing you'll want to watch out for when doing this, is that there might be a slight delay before the loading image appears, as its only being downloaded at the same time its needed.

Comment: Old bump; I find that replacing my submit button with this is fairly intuitive from the end users' point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You could attach the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events to the `div` containing the loading image.

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide() //hide the image initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: documentation says that ajaxStart and stop should only be attached to `document` since version 1.8

Answer (score 0):

On the event that fires off the Ajax request, that's where you show the div with your loading gif, then in the data success callback function of your Ajax call, you the hide the loading div. Good links here:

[How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation)