# XHR request is denoted as being cancelled although it seems to be successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

This is not really an issue, because the code works, **but** I am just curious as to why it happens.

I have the following jQuery code for an ajax post:

```
$.post('./add_fee_row/<?php echo $date; ?>',post, function(data){ ... });
```

It all works fine and dandy.

However in the Chrome Console it says: [image: what is going on here?]

Why does it say cancelled?

Everything happened as if the post was successful. Why does it say that?

(the php server code is available if needed)

*I am using Google Chrome version: 17.0.942.0*

Comment: When I was working with some calls to a Sinatra web service a while back I got the same issue and never figured it out, so I'm curious too.

Comment: Seems to be yet another great update from our friends @ chromium. I started to get those cancelled messages too. Also when using jQuery. Finally got rid of those annoying deprecated ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825448/webkit-issues-with-event-layerx-and-event-layery ) messages and now this :P

Comment: @PeeHaa naaah i still have the deprecated messages....

Comment: @Neal: I upgraded to 1.7 and before that I fixed it by removing the culprits.

Comment: It also can happen if you form submit via POST at the same time with XMLHTTPRequest. It's a case if you forgot to prevent default form submit but also trigger some XMLHTTPRequest at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in Chrome DevTools, it is already fixed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104920

Answer (score 0):

it may happen when Chrome sees that the actual data doesn’t match the headers.

If you return your answer with header type added, it shouldnt say canceled (Content-type: text/plain. for example)

You can check them by looking Event tabs - response headers.

Comment: My code specifically **has** a header type: `header('Content-type: application/json');`