# 'event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit.' Errors

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I just updated Chrome to version 16.0.912.63 and now I get hundreds of errors using jQuery 1.7.1. Seems to fire whenever the mouse is moved...

```
event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
```

Should I be worried about this? Is anyone else getting these errors?

My useragent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
```

**UPDATE:** In my case it was the Chrome extension "Search by Image (by Google) 1.1.0". I just had to disable it, it had nothing to do with my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebKit issues with event.layerX and event.layerY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825448/webkit-issues-with-event-layerx-and-event-layery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case it was the Chrome extension "Search by Image (by Google) 1.1.0"

Nothing to do with my application.

Disable it and you'll be free of these annoying errors.

Comment: I'm seeing these errors everywhere on my website and I don't have that chrome extension.

Comment: @Conrad.Dean have you disabled all other jQuery plugins and extensions?

Answer (score 11):

You should only worry about this if it is:

- your website and
- you are planning to upgrade jQuery to a version > 1.7 in the future and
- you are using `layerX` and `layerY` all over the place

The message is just telling you that those two properties are deprecated (at least in Webkit) and will be removed from jQuery in the near future.

Comment: It is my site. Should I wait for the next version of jQuery? or should I downgrade to version 1.7 of jQuery?

Comment: If you replace 1.7 with a newer version, layerX and layerY will stop working. So you should replace layerX and layerY in your code with whatever is supposed to replace it. Webkit will stop supporting layerX and layerY sometime in the future so you should no longer rely on them

Comment: Any ideas as to how I could find out what is using layerX and layerY?

Comment: Open the Javascript source code file(s) and search for "layerX" and/or "layerY"

Comment: I'm dumb, it wasn't my application at all, it was caused by an extension. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: which extension?  I think I'm having the same problem, and am horribly sick of the warning messages

Comment: @Kevin, in my case it was `Search by Image (by Google)1.1.0` that caused it! Disabling that fixed the thousands of warnings.

Comment: damn, the famous "always-the-very-last-jquery-version.js"-thing will just kill sites with "old" styles. i never thought that this update thing will make websites unuseable ? very nice bad side-effect of a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

add js to js file footer:

```
(function(){
    //remove layerX and layerY
    var all = $.event.props,
    len = all.length,
    res = [];
    while (len--) {
      var el = all[len];
      if (el != 'layerX' && el != 'layerY') res.push(el);
    }
    $.event.props = res;
}());
```

you can try it.