# event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebKit issues with event.layerX and event.layerY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825448/webkit-issues-with-event-layerx-and-event-layery)

I'm using jQuery 1.5.2 to finish my work , however the chrome reported warnings like "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future." There is no "layerX" and "layerY" in my javascript. Does anyone know what's going on ? Thanks .