# Design working in all browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, browser, compatibility

I have the following page:

http://www.bergstenmusic.com/test2 ---> Moved to here: http://www.bergstenmusic.com

I haven't been able to figure out why the plugin (Mosaic) will not present itself in IE. It works in every other browser I've tried and on mobile devices.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on it.

EDIT: I went through all my errors on W3C and fixed them one by one in CSS and then XHTML. One of them worked, I'm not sure which.

Comment: The Curse of Internet Explorer...

Comment: @Kimbie P. not an answer, but you should consider upgrading jQuery on that site while you are still in development phase. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825448/webkit-issues-with-event-layerx-and-event-layery

Comment: I confirmed that the mosaic thing doesn't show up in IE9 on my PC using your test URL... I then saved the page to an HTML file on my desktop using Save As in Google Chrome, opened the HTML file in Internet Explorer, and the mosaic shows up in the same IE9. Curious!

Comment: @Kimbie P. it looks like you didn't wrap your code in a `$(document).ready() { }`

Comment: @PeeHaa - I added the document bit, but it didn't change in IE.

Comment: @evilspoons - I did the same thing with the same result-- weird. I don't understand what would cause this. It was loading fine in IE one second, and then it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in your markup. IE is reporting that some comments are not being closed properly. Examples below but there are many more. Try removing the `!` in the closing tag

```
<!-- mosaic start--!>
<!-- AMPS--!>
<!--GUITARS--!>
...ETC
```

Chrome / FF seems to handle these and fixes them but IE isnt so it hiding the content as it hasnt seen the first comment closed.

The following examples are all legal comments:

```
 <!-- Hello -->
 <!-- Hello -- -- Hello-->
 <!---->
 <!------ Hello -->
 <!>
```

Source: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/misc/comment.html

Comment: I fixed these when I went to validate both XHTML and CSS, but it still won't displpay in IE.

Comment: The page has gone now? Can we see the problem? They were in there still when I checked earlier.

Comment: It's here now: http://www.bergstenmusic.com I finally got it working. I just went through every error that came up on W3C validation and fixed everything and now it's working. Although it looks horrendous in Opera, but at least the page works.

Comment: Yep! Thanks for your comments, they prompted me to error check, which is what fixed the problem :)