# bug in update content ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to write code for a task form which shows the task and it's status. This is my form.

[image]

If i click the status content a select menu will appear with the three options `Completed`,`In Progress`and `Waiting for client confirmation`. If i select an option and press enter it will be updated in the database. If the status is updated as `completed` then the select box should not display on the click event. My problem is if i updated the status to complete and then click the same status the select menu appears. But if i modified and refresh the page it works fine. I need it to be correct with out refresh the page.

This is my php code

```
<?php
            if($fetchstatus == 'Completed'){
            echo 'Completed';
            }
            else{?>
            <span id="status"><?php echo $fetchstatus; ?></span>
            <select id="<?php echo $fetchtaskid; ?>" style="width:110px;">
            <option value="In progress">In progress</option>
            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
            <option value="Waiting for client confirmation">Waiting for client confirmation</option>
            </select>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

This is my ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var eventFlag=false;
        var originalText='';
        $('.updatetask tr td span#status').click(function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $(this).siblings().show().focus();
            $(this).hide();
            eventFlag=false;
            originalText=$(this).siblings().val();
        });

        $('.updatetask tr td select').blur(function(e){
            if(!eventFlag && validate($(this))) doAjax($(this));
            else
            {
                $(this).siblings().show();
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

        $('.updatetask tr td select').keypress(function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if(code==13)
            {
                if(validate($(this)))
                {
                    doAjax($(this));
                    eventFlag=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).siblings().show();
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });

        function validate(input)
        {
            console.log(input.val()+" "+originalText);
            if(input.val()!='' && input.val()!=originalText)
            return true
            else return false;
        }

        function doAjax(input)
        {
            var formData="proId="+input.attr('id')+"&text="+input.val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_taskstatus.php",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data==1) 
                        {
                            input.siblings().text(input.val()).show();
                            input.hide();
                            if(input.val()=='completed')
                            {
                                input.siblings().unbind('click');
                            }   
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            input.siblings().show();
                            input.hide();
                            alert("something Wrong !");
                        }   
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert("Error:"+xhr.status+" "+thrownError);
                    }
                });
        }

    });
```

How can i correct that?

Comment: @designersvsoft, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've changed my code that I gave you yesterday so I'm a little bit confused and not sure whether my current code will work or not but from my guess try this and let me know the result

```
if(data==1) 
{
    input.siblings().text(input.val()).show();
    input.hide();
    if(input.val()=='Completed')
    {
        input.siblings().unbind('click');
    }   
}
```

Change the do ajax function, only the first if block, hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort heera. I have updated the ajax script in my question with your code. But it doesn't works correctly. Please see my question.

Comment: Amazing. you got it. Lots of thanks to you. I am sorry for didn't notice that spelling. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Welcome dear ! Pleasure is mine too.

Comment: Do you see this in your console "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future".

Comment: If it happens then go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825448/webkit-issues-with-event-layerx-and-event-layery

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.6.4.min.js. I didn't see any warning yet in all browsers. I couldn't understand what you have meant by console.