# Jquery mobile buttons not showing "button pressed" animation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

So while testing on my computer it works just fine, but as soon I test it on my phone it breaks...

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { data_role = "button", data_iconpos = "right", data_icon = "arrow-r", data_shadow = "false", @class = "arrowButton" })%>
```

That successfully renders a hyperlink styled like a button, and when pressed on my phone gives the appropriate feedback to let me know I pressed it. However this button here

```
<a id="submitBtn" href="" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="$('#formControl').submit();" >Sign In</a>
```

and EVERY OTHER BUTTON on the site (this was originally an input with type="submit" on it, but I changed it to make as much the same between the 2 as possible) won't show any feedback when you press them on my phone. Any ideas why this might be happening?

tl:dr Hyperlinks visually show clicks on my phone but buttons don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the statement

> Hyperlinks visually show clicks on my phone but buttons don't.

I think I know your problem.
See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/wBe9M/

```
<button data-role="button">Button with data role</button>            
<button>Button without data role</button>
```

When you specify **data-role** for **button**, it doesn't show button highlight or pressed animation, as data-role is not needed for button.

Comment: Only problem with this fiddle is that jQuery Mobile isn't being included, and once you add it then it works with all of the buttons

Comment: Its working for me, without adding anything else, I have put jQuery mobile ref for JS and CSS in "Manage Resources" tab.

Comment: I can get everything to work fine on my computer, but for some reason on all the mobile devices i've tested it still doesn't show up :\

Comment: can you make a fiddle or gist, having your problem? so I can execute, and help to solve you this problem.

Comment: I'm trying! The only problem is I'm having a lot of trouble reproducing anywhere else other than on my dev servers. After looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027441/jquery-mobile-hyperlink-button-animation-not-firing I think that my version is the issue. Thanks for the help though it is much appreciated... have some upvotes!