# Fancybox iframe working in compiler but not browser

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm having an issue with getting the fancybox iframe to load in the browser. I'm not sure what it is (I feel like it's something dumb) and I could use a hand.

The compiler has the lightbox working properly, but when I move it into my browser it's breaking. I thought it was an issue with my server, but when I open up the file directly from my desktop it still gives the same error. Any help is appreciated!

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/DTVLBjqueryfancybox2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/DTVLBjqueryfancybox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#various3").fancybox({
            'width'             : 1000,
            'height'            : 500,
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a id="various3" class="iframe" href="http://www.google.com">Iframe</a>
```

Comment: Haha...I really shouldn't call it a compiler. It's just Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you don´t have any Javascript errors on the page. When I load your page it starts with:

> GET http://www.localdtvdealer.com/Script/pageTracking.js  /justintest1/:7

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SaveAnalyticData is not defined   /justintest1/:39

And after clicking the link I get (besided an empty lightbox):

> event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

If this is a new project upgrade your [jQuery to 1.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825448/webkit-issues-with-event-layerx-and-event-layery).

> GET http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/blank.gif 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4

Add the missing image

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

I think this is the real issue right here. You are not allowed to embed the stuff you want to embed (other domain?). This is a security prevention error. It prevents malicious i-frames on pages.

Comment: That definitely fixed it! The main issue was that it wasn't from the same domain. Now it's giving me problems in IE. Apparently this is a pretty common problem. Thanks again!