# Grey out window onsubmit

Tags: jquery, search

I have a search that takes a long time to process... I have the submit setup to only allow the user to submit once.  However, I want a visual cue, like a greyed out window, to inform the user that a search is in progress.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question on this site which give pretty good details (with a walkthrough).

[How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation)

The only thing you'll have to change is to add the following:

```
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    showLoading();
  });
);
```