# how to display a loading gif when using jquery ui dialog iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this snippet of jquery code. I am trying to figure out a way to have a loading gif while this iframe loads. Thanks for any ideas.

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
.html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="/servlet/trainingServlet?method=editDoc&dir=<%=legDir%>&ID=-1" width="100%" height="580"></iframe>')
.dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     height: 575,
     width: 680,
     title: 'edit',
     position: [200, 100],
     buttons: {
         Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
     }
  });
  $dialog.dialog('open');
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reveal a CSS div just after `dialog.open()` and then have the `loadServlet` HTML hide it again when it's loaded.  Something like:

```
$dialog.dialog.open();
$("#loading").show()
```

See [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation)

Comment: thanks, but this does not really show inside the dialog. I guess thats what i am asking how to do it

Comment: For it to show inside the dialog, you'll have to have the servlet's output be ...loading, then replaced in the $(document).ready() block.  But it sounds like you already know this.  You should look into using $.ajax.load() to fetch the servlet.  Then you can

Comment: ..sorry... should say....then you can bind events to the start and end of the ajax call.  Again, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-waiting-loading-animation -- scroll down to the 2nd answer -- explains this quite well.