# jQuery loading window while waiting for long function to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I'm trying to adapt this solution to my needs: [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

Basically a really awesome scheme is provided to wrap Ajax requests with a nice loading GUI. I'm trying to do the same for a function I have that does some calculations and then appends some graphics to the DOM.

So what I've tried is this:

```
$("body").addClass("loading");
long_time_taking_function(mainDiv);
$("body").removeClass("loading");
```

Unfortunately it appears as though the class is added and then removed instantly, either before or after the long_time_taking_function() executes. However I know that adding the class works, because commenting out the removeClass() call keeps the gif floating on the page.

Any ideas how I can make this work? I can provide more details about the intermediate function if needed.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, the contents of `long_time_taking_function` would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: It does this: 
1. Sort a big JSON object by a particular field
2. Create a highcharts object (http://www.highcharts.com/) and append it to the main div element
That's all.

Comment: Where are you getting the big JSON object?

Comment: Generated from elsewhere.. It's actually a variable that's included in another .js file.

Comment: I see. In that case, I think it's quite possible that your `long_time_taking_function` does not take that long after all. Try profiling it by surrounding the call with `console.time('t1');` and `console.timeEnd('t1');` and viewing the console (F12 in Firefox or Chrome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pitfall with AJAX: the first "A" stands for "asynchronous".  That means that the AJAX call returns immediately and runs more-or-less "in the background".  `long_time_taking_function()` contains an AJAX call.  You just need to move that `$('body').removeClass('loading')` into the callback of the AJAX call. If you're using jQuery (assuming you are since you tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)), it will look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...options...
}).always(function(response) {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
});
```

Edit: the jQuery Deferred object's callback here should be `always()`, as the loading class should be removed even if the ajax call failed.

Comment: I don't think I'm using AJAX though. Hence why I made this topic. All my function does is update the DOM by adding some javascript-generated images, does that count as AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a call back to your function so that when it is finished, it will call your removeClass statement.

Something like this:

```
     //declare your functions
     function long_time_taking_function(mainDiv, callback){

        //...your code...
        callback();
     }

     function removeLoadGif(){
         $("body").removeClass("loading");
     }



     //in your current code call this
     $("body").addClass("loading");
     long_time_taking_function(mainDiv, removeLoadGif);
```

Or you could just add the line `$("body").removeClass("loading");` to the end of your function long_time_taking_function. If the body currently doesn't have the class, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this...

```
$("body").addClass("loading");
doSomething(url,params)
  .complete(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
  });
```

In your code, addClass and removeClass are executed so fast it's like nothing ever happened.