# JQuery AJAX synchronous request behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax address validation function that I am trying to call synchronously, like this:

```
function validate_address(address, city, state, zip) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/address',
        data: {
            address: address,
            city: city,
            state: state,
            zip: zip
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}
```

Before I call the function, I display a spinning gif and hide it after the function:

```
$('#spinner').show();
var res = validate_address(address, city, state, zip);
$('#spinner').hide();
```

The issue is that the `show()` and `hide()` functions both get called AFTER the ajax call is completed.

I verified this by adding a 5 second delay to the ajax call, server-side. `show()` and `hide()` were both called immediately after each other 5 seconds after I triggered this sequence.

Before you call me out, I know that synchronous requests are not encouraged. In this case, I do have to use a synchronous call. I'm just trying what's going on here and how to fix it.

Comment: "This is not the Ajax you are looking for", you should be using asynchronous requests, no matter what excuse you may have for locking the browser?

Comment: jQuery animation's does not wait for other functions. Take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: Why do you think you had to do a synchronous call? Imo this is the reason for the DOM not getting rendered between the show and hide calls (and yes, it *is executed before* the ajax call)

Comment: @Bergi That's kind of what I'm thinking. Executed but not rendered until the call is done, at that point they get rendered right after each other

Comment: @nathancahill: Yes, it seems you will need to make the call asynchronous. What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: should also note in docs that `async: false` is deprecated.

Comment: I have a series of views with forms that I'm stepping through. If the view doesn't validate, it shouldn't show the next view.

Comment: ^ Now that I read that, it sounds stupid. Just refactored all of my code around callbacks and everything works. Thanks for the help @Bergi and adeneo, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're already returning the deferred from the ajax function, so just use `done()` :

```
$('#spinner').show();
validate_address(address, city, state, zip).done(function(data) {
    res = data;
    $('#spinner').hide();
});
```

This would even work with an asynchronous request ?

If the showing of the spinner is still to slow, and you'd like to degrade user experience even more, you can always use a callback:

```
$('#spinner').show(1000, function() {
    validate_address(address, city, state, zip).done(function(data) {
        res = data;
        $('#spinner').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: No, he does return the `responseText`

Comment: I added a number of console.log calls. The code above works fine in Firefox. Safari doesn't animate or log anything until the ajax call is finished. Chrome logs before and after the request, but doesn't animate anything.

Comment: @nathancahill - what Bergi said above. Remove the responseText line!

Answer (score 0):

what about `ajaxStart` and `ajaxEnd`

Take a look at this post : [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

```
$("body").on({
    // When ajaxStart is fired, add 'loading' to body class
    ajaxStart: function() { 
        $(this).addClass("loading");  // or do what you need here 
    },
    // When ajaxStop is fired, rmeove 'loading' from body class
    ajaxStop: function() { 
        $(this).removeClass("loading"); // or do what you need here 
    }    
});
```