# How to create a page loading animation for a website?

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, loading-animation

Is there anyway to create a loading or "please wait" animation while a website is loading?

Comment: You may have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation

Answer (score 2):

there are tons of options, try to google gif loader or just use this http://www.ajaxload.info/