# Is there any jquery plugin for loader image before page gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did lot of google for the plugin but i am not getting. If you know any plugin please inform me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You want a loading image?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: when my page gets loaded before that loader image should be displayed and when page gets loaded completely the loader image should vanish. This is my requirement

Comment: i don't sure of catching right what you mean, anyway, look at this plugin. I guess your mean something like it. https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

Comment: this link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation

Answer (score 2):

Its is called `pagepreloader`.

[***`Plugin`***](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/)

[***`Example`***](http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/)

Comment: https://github.com/niklausgerber/PreLoadMe

Comment: I want this plugin. But it is not working when I apply it to my page.

Comment: @AnandJaju make sure jQuery is not conflicting with other and use jQuery that plugin required...also use firebug firefox add-on to see what error are occured..

Comment: I have inserted that js and css files and also uploaded it to server but then also it is not working.

Comment: @AnandJaju can i see that on live.???

Comment: yah check this one: http://eywaz.com/sit2/Fairmacs%20Shipstore05-03-2013/home.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26716/discussion-between-anand-jaju-and-dipesh-parmar)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) or [base64](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) encoded images (alternative solution)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any plugin for this 
try this simply.. image tag must be next to body tag

```
<body>
<div id="loading"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"></div>
 .
 .
 .

</body>
```

and place this with in script tag

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#loading").hide(); 
});
```

the css for loading div

```
#loading {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```