# Ajax Animation JQuery 1.9.2

Tags: jquery, ajax

How would i upgrade the solution provided in this question
[How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation/1964871#1964871)

to work with JQuery 1.9.2?

I can't seem to get it to work.
I've tried the following
http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/2485/

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   $("body").addClass("loading"); });
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   $("body").removeClass("loading"); });
```

but that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to do this (using `ajaxStop()` for the second one):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   $("body").addClass("loading"); });
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){   $("body").removeClass("loading"); });
```

See it working here on a modified version of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gk3RL/

---

Also, a little more efficient to use `document.body` instead of `"body"`:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   $(document.body).addClass("loading"); });
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){   $(document.body).removeClass("loading"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The second event should be `ajaxComplete`

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){   $("body").removeClass("loading"); });
```