# Fade In Ajax Start animation

Tags: jquery, ajax

As per the question I asked here:
[Ajax Animation JQuery 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670665/ajax-animation-jquery-1-9-2)

I'm using an animation to highlight the AJAX data refresh.
However it's a bit obtrusive when most of the time the refresh takes less than half a second.
I'd like to fade the animation in.

Here's the updated fiddle provided by the previous answer:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gk3RL/)

So we have the code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("body").addClass("loading");
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
});
```

I've tried a number of things such as putting additional paramters into the add class
addClass("loading",500)
addClass("loading",500,500)

and putting .fadeIn(500);
in a number of places but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

How can I fade the DIV in?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's `delay()` and make your `.modal` element fade in and out.

Here's an updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gk3RL/1/.

It amounts to this: `$.ajaxStart(function () { $('.modal').delay(500).fadeIn(); });`
jQuery will wait for half a second before doing the fade in. In the `$.ajaxStop` you may need to do `stop()` to prevent the delayed `fadeIn` from firing if the request finishes within the delay.

Unfortunately, the `delay()` cannot be cancelled. So maybe the most robust solution would be to use JavaScript's own `setTimeout`, which can be cancelled by calling `clearTimeout`.

So then you'd do this:

```
var timeOut;

$.ajaxStart(function () {
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.modal').fadeIn();
    }, 500); // Waits for half a second before fading .modal in
});

$.ajaxStop(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeOut); // Cancels if request finished < .5 seconds
    $('.modal').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Good call on the cleared timeout.  That works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually fade the modal in.

CSS:

```
/* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
   Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
   with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
   speak for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
   our animation centered, and no-repeating */
 .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8) url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
 body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("body").addClass("loading");
    $('.modal').fadeIn(500);
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
    $('.modal').fadeOut(500);
});

// Initiates an AJAX request on click
$(document).on("click", function () {
    $.post("/mockjax");
});


// http://code.appendto.com/plugins/jquery-mockjax
$.mockjax({
    url: '/mockjax',
    responseTime: 2000
});
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/licson0729/gk3RL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
function startAjaxLoader() {
    $("#ajaxLoader").delay(500).fadeIn(750);
}

function stopAjaxLoader() {
    $("#ajaxLoader").stop(true).hide();
}

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    startAjaxLoader();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    stopAjaxLoader();
}).ajaxError(function(ajaxErrorEvent, jqXHR) {
    stopAjaxLoader();
    // Display error
});
```

The method `.stop(true)` cancels all events and animations running or queued.