# Set delay time for loading page

Tags: animation, loading, delay

It's there any way to set a page loading time?

I wan't to make a loading animation for may web page (This one: [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)), and i can't see if it works because the page is loading too fast,all most instantly.

Comment: mmmh, I think you're taking the problem the wrong way. If your page is loading slowly, you should find a way to speed it up cause loading and running yet another animation won't help. Anyway, as an aswer to your question, I would suggest placing heavy images on your page only for test purpose, so that it takes ages to load.

Comment: Please don't do that. If your page is loading fast then that would be the best user experience. Unnecessary delay will annoy and drive ppl away from your website.

Comment: I wan't to set the telay time JUST TO SEE IF THE LOADING ANIMATIN WORKS. After that i will disable this delay. It's just for a test. Thanks  Bartdude! I will try.