# displaying image before the link returned through php

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink

I want to display image before the link returned through php.
Below is the ajax code

```
$.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST",
    url: "dbtryout2_2.php",
    data: datastr,
    success: function (arrayphp) {
        //how to display image before this link
        var link = $('<a href="#" class="my-class">' + arrayphp + '</a>');
        $(".searchby .searchlist").append(link);

    }
});
```

Comment: I fail to see anything like a question here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery "Please Wait, Loading..." animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the image before the link.

```
$.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST",
    url: "dbtryout2_2.php",
    data: datastr,
    success: function (arrayphp) {
        //how to display image before this link
        var link = $('' + arrayphp + '');
        var image = "<img src='http://www.yourdomain.com/iamge.png' alt='' />"
        $(".searchby .searchlist").append(image).append(link);

    }
});
```

Comment: @ LAURYNAS iam displaying links one by one through php from inside a loop and i want the image to be displayed before each link but here the image is getting displayed before only the first link and not getting displayed before rest of the links

Comment: $(".searchby .searchlist a").prepend(image); that should do the trick

Comment: @  LAURYNAS i have edited ur code to wat my actual code is.The trick u told is not working.I have described my problem in comment

Comment: you must give me more details on what is returned by the ajax call. i can not help you if i do not know what code is returned there and what is your html

Comment: @ Laurynas now iam clear with my problem.You see the arrayphp argument in my code.I was thinking that php sends one value at a time .But actually php sends all the elements that are to be echoed one by one from inside a loop at once to the arrayphp argument thats why all the elements are getting displayed as one link and the image is getting dispalyed only once