# How to avoid "white screen in phonegap application" when we load data to the page from server in android app?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jQuery mobile, I am facing the  problem while I load data from the server,in between a white screen will appear before the new page shows up, I see white screen  when I make request to the server

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery Loader while Data is loading.

See from the below links:
http://www.aplusdesign.com.au/blog/jquery-ajax-loader-spinner/

[How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)