# Changes to DOM should be visible before Ajax calls are executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am working on some improvements for a shopping cart (Gambio GX2 shop software). When the customer updates the quantity of the products, he should see a loading gif while the cart is updated. This is done by applying the class `.modal` (see CSS) to the body (using JQuery's `.addClass`). After that, some ajax calls are executed and in the end the cart is submitted and the page is reloaded.

This works perfectly in Firefox, but it has issues in other Browsers. In Chrome, all the Ajax calls are executed first, and only then the gif loading animation is visible (while the page reloads). In Safari, the gif animation doesn't shop up at all.

If I set a break point in the debugger, then I can see the gif animation immediately (step by step execution), but as soon as I let it run its normal course, it seems that the order is not correct.

**So in short: How can I make sure that the visual changes are applied before the ajax calls are exectuted?**

I have the following function (simplified for example's sake)

**JS**

```
$('.button_cart_refresh').live('click', function (event) {

    $("body").addClass("loading"); // Show "loading" gif

    var coo_quantity_checker = new GMOrderQuantityChecker();
    var t_result = coo_quantity_checker.check_cart(); // Trigger Ajax calls

    if (t_result == true) {
        $('#cart_quantity').trigger("submit", [true]);
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass("loading");
    }
    return false;
});
```

**CSS** (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964871/1131823)

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4 )
    url('img/ajax-sheep-loader.gif')
    50% 50%
    no-repeat;
}

body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That `.check_cart()` function involves a synchronous ajax call, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `.check_cart()` involves a synchronous ajax call. That means that the browser will be completely stuck waiting for it to finish; that's what "synchronous" means in this situation.

So, first: **you should not use synchronous ajax if you can help it (and you almost always can).**

That said (stridently), you could do your ajax call and subsequent work after a brief timeout:

```
$('.button_cart_refresh').live('click', function (event) {

    $("body").addClass("loading"); // Show "loading" gif

    var coo_quantity_checker = new GMOrderQuantityChecker();
    setTimeout(function() {
      var t_result = coo_quantity_checker.check_cart(); // Trigger Ajax calls

      if (t_result == true) {
        $('#cart_quantity').trigger("submit", [true]);
      } else {
        $("body").removeClass("loading");
      }
    }, 15);
    return false;
});
```

Also you should stop using `.live()` as it's been deprecated for years.

Comment: You are right, Pointy, it is indeed a synchronous ajax call. After implementing your changes, the loading gif is displayed, but unfortunately the animation stops as soon as the ajax call is triggered. Surprisingly this doesn't happen in Firefox. Any idea how that might be avoided? Other than making the ajax call asynchronously? I don't want to get too deep into the existing shop software (but I will probably have to, it seems).

Comment: @TrashyMcTrash well that's the problem with synchronous ajax - the browser has to wait for the HTTP transaction to complete, and I guess some browsers really wait and do nothing else. The best fix is to stop using synchronous ajax. It's really a terrible idea and it would have been better if browsers never implemented it.