# mockjax loader - stop from running for specific function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loader, preloader, mockjax

I am making use of Jonathan Sampson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation) for my jquery busy loader. it works 100% and detects any jquery posting or the like and shows the loader.

my problem is that most times I want the user to wait when I fetch info from the database so happy for the loader to appear.

What I want however, is for certain functions only for the loader not to show when I save info to the database.

the fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/4952/)

for example, the below causes the loader to run. how can I modify this so mockjax knows not to run for this function only?

```
$(document).on("click", function(){
    $.get("/mockjax");        
});
```

Thanks for the help as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version (with code)**

Click the heading - **Animation**

Click the paragraph - **No Animation**

**http://jsfiddle.net/hPS2v/**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/mockjax",
    type: "GET",
    global: false //This is the key
});
```

--

**The slightly longer version**

There is a great variable available in the $.ajax() method which let's you stop ajax events from firing (but not the ajax itself). This is called **global**. From the docs

> **global** (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Whether to trigger global Ajax
>   event handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to
>   prevent the global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being
>   triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.

With this in mind, I have slightly changed your code a little to demonstrate how we can make this work.

1) Moved the AJAX call into a function with 2 parameters: URL and eventTrigger. Basically we want the URL to be "/mockajax", and the eventTrigger to be true or false (depending on if and when you want to show your animation)

2) I took the event handler off the $(document) and added 2 events to the heading tags and the p tags so I can demonstrate the AJAX working in 2 places with the same code (1 with and 1 without an animation)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable as a flag which denotes your preference of not showing the loader.

```
//let say, showLoader, by default true
var showLoader = true;
```

Now, add this to your ajax setup as required.

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () {
        // if showLoader true, then shows loading image
        if (showLoader)
            $body.addClass("loading");
    },
    ajaxStop: function () {
        $body.removeClass("loading");
        // set showLoader to true
        showLoader = true;
    }
});
```

Change `showLoader` state as required by you.

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    // if target element is anchor tag, then do not show loading image - example
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
        showLoader = false;
    }
    $.get("/mockjax");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/5177/

Hope, it helps.