# Asp.net Display UpdateProgress on PostBackTrigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an UpdatePanel with the following Triggers:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlNames" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPullReport"/> 
</Triggers>
```

When the SelectedIndexChanged event is triggered I can see my loading gif from the UpdateProgress but when I click the `btnPullReport` button I do not.

It must be of type PostBackTrigger or else I get error:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
```

The btnPullReport creates an Excel file and prompts the user to save it.

The last lines in the btnPullReport_Click are these:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Report.xlsx");
package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

The error happens at `Response.End();` and it states: `{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}`

How can I make it so that it displays the UpdateProgress bar after clicking the button also?

Answer (score 0):

First, UpdateProgress shows only on asynchronous postbacks, your button is a "PostBackTrigger" and not an "AsyncPostBackTrigger". You must know also that UpdateProgress will not show if the response is received quickly, see the DisplayAfter property [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.updateprogress.displayafter(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.updateprogress.displayafter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Second, on partial updates the server side code must not use the Page.Response object, because this alter the response format. See this for more info http://forums.asp.net/p/1083296/1607033.aspx

Comment: I see. So it is impossible to display the loading bar in my case. It must be set as a PostBackTrigger only in order to work.

Comment: Why did you define btnPullReport as trigger for the UpdatePanel ? Did it modify the content of the UpdatePanel ? If yes, you are perforce wrong, cause when you call response.clear() the browser will not receive those modifications. Can you give us the entire  btnPullReport_Click code.

Comment: If I don't call it as a trigger it crashes on the error above. If I do it actually works just fine and creates the file. It just doesn't show the UpdateProgress.

Comment: Is the btnPullReport inside your UpdatePanel ?

Comment: Yes. It is inside a table which is inside the panel.

Comment: You have like a dilemmas: if you set the button as AsyncPostBackTrigger the UpdateProgress will not show, and if you set it the Response.Clear will cause the error, please see the solution I suggest you on my next answer.

Comment: So the reason it there is because I also have some listboxes which need to share data but the Click method of the button which only work if the button is also in the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion, I suggest you this:
- On your UpdatePanel set the ChildrenAsTriggers Attribute to False.
- Dont define the button as a trigger for the UpdatePanel (nor Sync or Async)
- Use a manuel mechanism to show an UpdateProgress when the button is clicked. Like this one [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)