# JQuery .show() method not Working After .hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a JQuery script that allows a checkbox (its class name is "adminCheckBox") to show or hide various objects on the screen based on whether or not it is checked.

The hiding function works fine. However, after the elements have been hidden and I press the checkbox again, the elements do not appear again. Are there any ideas as to why this may be? Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".adminCheckbox").click(function(){

           if(!document.getElementsByClassName("adminCheckBox").checked){

            $(".deleteImageButton").hide(500);
            $(".addHeading").hide(500);
            $(".deleteHeadingButton").hide(500);
            $(".fileUpload").hide(500);
            $(".fileUploadSubmit").hide(500);    

           }else{

            $(".deleteImageButton").show();
            $(".addHeading").show();
            $(".deleteHeadingButton").show();
            $(".fileUpload").show();
            $(".fileUploadSubmit").show();    

           }    

        }); 
        });
```

Below is the HTML for the checkbox in question.

```
        <br><div class="adminControls"><input type="checkbox" class="adminCheckbox"         checked="checked"><div class="checkBoxText">&nbsp;&nbsp;Admin Controls</div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend just using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead for this. Shorten up the code a lot just with that. Also, you can further optimize it just by giving all those elements a same class, if you want.

```
$(".adminCheckbox").click(function(){

    $(".deleteImageButton, .addHeading, .deleteHeadingButton, .fileUpload, .fileUploadSubmit").toggle();

});
```

You can also place a number value for toggle to do an animation on hide and show, like `.toggle(500)`

Comment: Effective solution, sure, but still, why on earth won't show() work after hide()??? This was actually the real question, rather than asking for a workaround, and since I just stumbled across the exactly same problem in jQuery myself, I'm indeed interested in the reason for why you cannot use show() after hide() - it seems like a really big bug in jQuery to me?!?

Comment: still in some cases we need explicitly to show or hide

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to hide and show your buttons.

And use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event/handler instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

**According to the jQuery API:**

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.adminCheckbox').on('change', function () {
        $(".deleteImageButton, .addHeading, .deleteHeadingButton, .fileUpload, .fileUploadSubmit").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CETx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since `document.getElementsByClassName("adminCheckBox")` returns an array, the `checked` property will not be defined.  Consider using `document.getElementsByClassName("adminCheckBox")[0]` or iterating through the array properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


?>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#lap1").click(function(){
prodtype="laptop";
$("#cam").hide();
$("#mob").hide();
$("#scarves").hide();
$("#bag").hide();
$("#glass").hide();
$("#pants").hide();
$("#jw").hide();
$("#sand").hide();
$("#lapy").show(function(){

rates=document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i=0;i<rates.length;i++)
{
rates[i].checked=false;
}

});


$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'alldisplay.php',
        data:"prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });

});





$("#came").click(function(){
prodtype="camera";

$("#mob").hide();
$("#scarves").hide();
$("#bag").hide();
$("#glass").hide();
$("#pants").hide();
$("#jw").hide();
$("#sand").hide();
$("#lapy").hide();
$("#cam").show(function(){

rates=document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i=0;i<rates.length;i++)
{
rates[i].checked=false;
}
});

$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'alldisplay.php',
        data:"prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });
});



$("#mobi").click(function(){

prodtype="mobile";

$("#scarves").hide();
$("#bag").hide();
$("#glass").hide();
$("#pants").hide();
$("#jw").hide();
$("#sand").hide();
$("#lapy").hide();
$("#cam").hide();
$("#mob").show(function(){

rates=document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i=0;i<rates.length;i++)
{
rates[i].checked=false;
}
});

$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'alldisplay.php',
        data:"prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });

});




$("#scrv").click(function(){

prodtype="clothes";

$("#scarves").hide();
$("#bag").hide();
$("#glass").hide();
$("#pants").hide();
$("#jw").hide();
$("#sand").hide();
$("#lapy").hide();
$("#cam").hide();
$("#mob").hide();
$("#scarves").show(function(){

rates=document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i=0;i<rates.length;i++)
{
rates[i].checked=false;
}
});


$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'alldisplay.php',
        data:"prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });
});




$("#bagg").click(function(){

prodtype="bags";

$("#scarves").hide();

$("#glass").hide();
$("#pants").hide();
$("#jw").hide();
$("#sand").hide();
$("#lapy").hide();
$("#cam").hide();
$("#mob").hide();
$("#bag").show(function(){

rates=document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i=0;i<rates.length;i++)
{
rates[i].checked=false;
}
});



$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'alldisplay.php',
        data:"prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });
});



$("#glasss").click(function(){

prodtype="glass";

$("#scarves").hide();
$("#pants").hide();
$("#jw").hide();
$("#sand").hide();
$("#lapy").hide();
$("#cam").hide();
$("#mob").hide();
$("#bag").hide();
$("#glass").show(function(){

rates=document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i=0;i<rates.length;i++)
{
rates[i].checked=false;
}
});



$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'alldisplay.php',
        data:"prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });
});


$("#left").click(function(){
rates = document.getElementsByName('lap');
for(var i = 0; i < rates.length; i++){
    if(rates[i].checked){
        rate_value = rates[i].value;
        alert(rate_value);
        $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'branddisplay.php',
        data:'brand='+rate_value+"&prodtype="+prodtype,
        success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=response;
        }
        });
    }
}

});

});

</script>

<center>
<div id="menu" style="font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;height:30px;width:800px;background-color:#A0A0A0 ">
<span id="lap1">laptop&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<span  id="came">camera&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<span  id="mobi">mobile&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<span  id="scrv">Scarves&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<span  id="bagg">Bag&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<span  id="glasss">Glass&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>

</div>
</center><br>
<div id="left" style="float:left;text-decoration:none;height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:#66CCFF ">
<div id="lapy">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="sony" /> sony<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="samsuze" /> samsuze<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="sony " /> sony<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="tosiba" /> tosiba<br />
</form> 
</div>
<div id="cam">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="sony" /> sony<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="niccon" /> niccon<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="fijjj" /> fijjj<br />

</form>
</div>
<div id="mob">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="lg" /> lg<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="samsuze" /> samsuze<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="samsuze" /> samsuze<br />
</form>
</div>
<div id="scarves">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="simple" /> simple<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="cool" />cool <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="curvi" /> carvi<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="cafu" /> cafu<br />
</form>
</div>
<div id="bag">
<form>
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="Bag1" /> Bag1<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="Bag2" />Bag2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="Bag3" /> Bag3<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="Bag4" /> Bag4<br />
</form>
</div>
<div id="glass">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="reben1" /> reben1<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="reben2" />reben2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="reben3" /> reben3<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="reben4" /> reben4<br />
</form>
</div>

<div id="pants">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="levis" /> levis <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="gazz" />gazz <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="disel" /> disel <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="killer" /> killer <br />
</form>
</div>

<div id="jw">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="gold" /> gold<br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="gold" />gold <br />

</form>
</div>
<div id="sand">

<form name="input"  method="get">
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="parago" />  paragon <br />
<input type="radio" name="lap" value="paragon" />  paragon <br />


</form>
</div>

</div >
<center>
<div id="right" style="margin-left:40px;float:left;text-decoration:none;height:900px;width:900px;background-color:#FFFFFF">
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("seo",$con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM search";
$response=mysql_query($sql,$con);

echo "<table border='1'> ";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($response))
{

echo "<tr><td>Product name:".$row['pname']."<br>Product Type:".$row['ptype']."<br>City Name:".$row['cname'];

echo "<td><img style='margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;height:100px;width:100px' src='upload/".$row['pimg']."'/></tr>";
//echo $row['pimg'];
}

echo "</table>";
 ?>
</div></center>
```

i did this way. refer if you like....

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from document.getElementsByClassName and the return as an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/c964v/

```
$(".adminCheckbox").click(function(){
    if(!$(".adminCheckbox").is(":checked")){
        $(".deleteImageButton").hide(500);   
    }else{               
        $(".deleteImageButton").show();           
    }  
});
```

See u!