# Showing loading indication while loading XML

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that I load my data from XML files to DIVs.
In this Example I have `DIV` with this attribute: `class="Group"`;
Also this is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get(Root + "/Feed_Products/Groups", {}, function (xml) {
        var output = '';
        $('item', xml).each(function (i) {
            var Name = $(this).find("Name").text();
            var Id = $(this).find("Id").text();

            var Link = Root + '/Group' + Id;

            output += '<a href="' + Link + '">' + Name + '</a>';
        });
        $(".Group").append(output);
    });
});
```

As you know, loading XML has delay and its not as fast as direct database request.

How can I show small loading GIF on each DIV that is loading XML?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPWcg.png

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. My question is different. If you see in my code, loading XML is after `Document Loaded` event. So,,, my main loading image was shown and hided before. After that loading image, I wanna show small loading images on different DIVs. An example for my question is `Inbox` of Stackoverflow loading image that is separated from its main loading. Another exmple is Facebook and Twitter lazy loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Group").addClass("loading");
    $.get(Root + "/Feed_Products/Groups", {}, function (xml) {

        var output = '';
        $('item', xml).each(function (i) {
            var Name = $(this).find("Name").text();
            var Id = $(this).find("Id").text();

            var Link = Root + '/Group' + Id;

            output += '<a href="' + Link + '">' + Name + '</a>';
        });
        $(".Group").append(output).removeClass("loading");

    });
});
```

Then in your css define :

```
.Group.loading{
   background-image: url("yourGIF.gif");
   /* other rules */
}
```

Comment: That's true. I wanna use a global code which is stored in a `ContentManagerFile.js` file.

Comment: Dear @Charleshaa,,, There are too many of these type of requests in my page and I haven't access to code. Because this website is based on ASP.NET MVC (Closed Source) and I'm just a content manager!

Comment: Ah ok, well first, if you do not have access to code, why ask us how to do it ? Second, the answer I gave you works even if you have hundreds of DIVs in the page.

Comment: This code works without any problem and your answer is respected for me! But this is not something that I want!

Comment: Ok... Then what do you want ? If my answer works for what you asked, you need to click _accept answer_

Comment: My friend @Charleshaa I told you that I am just a content manager in this company!

Comment: Lol yes I got that, but how would you want to do it if you cannot change the code ?? You seem very confused

Comment: I'm glad to hear that... That code is store in dynamic pages and we dont have FTP access to them. Each content manager in our company has access to a CSS and JS File that is auto generated on page based on admins Username. e.g-> headadmin.js , mrt.js , tayyebi.js , ...

Comment: Ok... I got a bit more details here, that's a good start. So you cannot change _ANY_ code ? right ?

Comment: Yes. Just I have access to my JS file on page and a FTP access to a limited folder that contains my JS and CSS file.

Comment: Well... if you use the code I gave you and put it in your JS file which you have access to, it should work. I do not understand your concern. Just put the GIF in your folder, and use an absolute path to your GIF in the CSS.

Comment: I dont have reputation to put this image in my post: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BPWcg.png

Comment: Ok my friend. I think I can't ask my question clear! I will accept your answer but please think on my question.

Comment: I understand your Question, and I answered it I think. The fact that you cannot change the HTML is not on our hands. Just ask the developer at your company to check my answer if he has trouble.