# jQuery Variable not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having some problems with jQuery Variables. As I am kind of a newbie, maybe I am doing something wrong, but here it is:

```
var loading = jQuery('#loading');
        loading.hide();
        jQuery(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                loading.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                loading.hide();
            });
```

What I am trying to do is, show my "loading" div while ajax is running, but the variable "loading" just seem to not work. If I use jQuery('#loading') everywhere instead of the variable it is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation

Comment: If you do not have your js in the foot, or wrap your js in a `ready` block the `div#loading` will not exist to be queried yet. Also if your `div#loading` doesn't have `display:none;` on it `show()` will not work. Hard to tell without seeing the actual structure of your js and html.

Comment: use loading = loading.id;

Answer (score -1):

`jQuery` and `$.` act differently. Try using `$` for this job like:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var loading = $('#loading');
        loading.hide();
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){loading.show()});
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){loading.hide()});
});
```

Comment: where are you getting this information? jQuery and $ are the same variable.