# jQuery Loading Animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation, request

I'm facing a little problem with following solution of Jonathan Sampson: [jQuery “Please Wait, Loading…” animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

I'm using jQuery 2.1.3 and I can't seem to get it work.

```
$body = $("body");
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("body").addClass("loading");
    $('.modal').fadeIn(500);
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
    $('.modal').fadeOut(500);
});
```

My footer.php looks like this. All links are working and I don't even get an error.

```
<div class="modal"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>       
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Magnific-Popup-master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/kswedberg-jquery-smooth-scroll-dc770ba/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

When I add the "loading" class manually in firebug to my body it is working. So I assume it's an jQuery problem. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Is `$.ajax()` called ? `"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3  /jquery.min.js"` space after "2.1.3" ?

Comment: To be honestly I don't know, it's my first time working with ajax. Isn't an ajax request sent everytime I reload the my page? I thought on click in the js fiddle was just to demonstrate it easier.

Comment: No . Have to call `$.ajax()`

Comment: I want the ajax event starts to be fired everytime someone is (re)loading my page. How would I do that?

Comment: Call `$.ajax()` , see _"**When an ajax event starts**, we add the "loading" class to the body. and when events are done, we remove the "loading" class from the body."_ at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1964871/2801559 ? , or try http://api.jquery.com/ready . If possible , can post included `html` , `js` ?

Comment: Yeah I get that, but as I already wrote at the beginning I thought an ajax event starts everytime you reload the page. My problem is now, I want the ajax to be fired everytime I reload how do I do that. By simply adding `$.ajax()`? I just uploaded the current js, you can see  it [here](http://www.raphaellechner.com/).

Comment: Yes . If requirement is to utilize `$.ajax` `events` , could call `$.ajax()` at each page load

Comment: So do I have to call ajax on load? Could you probably write a code snippet it's not working for me with that method.

Comment: Thanks for the work mate but it won't work unfortunately.

Comment: If possible , can  describe _"won't work"_ ?

Comment: I just checked it again and it's working now. The request was just so short that I couldn't see it at first.

Comment: My problem is following now: It's just appearing for a mere second, but I want it to be seen as long as the site's content is still loading (the images for example).

I thought this ajax method is just an jQuery alternative for the native javascript?  `window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function load()
    {
        window.removeEventListener('load', load, false);
        document.body.classList.remove('loading');
    },
    false); `

Comment: Yes . The `duration` property of `fadeIn` , `fadeOut` is total 1 second ; or `500` ,  `500` respectively . Description of requirement at OP appear to seek solution for displaying notification for `$.ajax()` request ? , not displaying notification during loading of multiple assets at page load  ?

Comment: Yeah it SHOULD be 1 second in total, but the fade isn't working at all. Its just a milisecond that it appears. As i wrote, I linked the preloader animation I was having problems with. Thats what I want to achieve, just a simple loader that appears till the iamges are loaded for most of the users (i know you cant really track it for everyone). If that doesnt work I guess I just want to show the loader for 1-2 seconds is that possible?

Comment: If open `console` , select `network` tab , view `timeline` section , perhaps possible to "see" assets loading / load time. Total page load time appear  27-30 seconds ; `iphone-bubble.png` taking 30 seconds alone to load . Try changing `fadeIn` , `fadeOut` to between `14000` - `15000` each .

Comment: As i said before already, the fade isn't working at all, there was no 1 second fade before and there is no fade now, it just ignores the fade and shows the modal div for a mere second, i uploaded it as well.

Comment: Remove `DOMContentLoaded` , replace with original `ajaxStop` . The piece at OP not necessarily implemented for loading all assets . Viewed `network` tab at `console` ? Tried adjusting `fadeIn` , `fadeOut` durations to `14000` each ?

Comment: I already removed the `DOMContentLoaded`. I'm not saying "The fade is not working" just for fun. I tried it out and it just doesn't work. Maybe "find" is not working at all.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/p8xtL2xv/

Comment: It seems to work now, I'll try to decrease the loading time a bit now and probably adjust the fade time according to that. Thanks a lot for the hard work, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on({
   ajaxStart: function() {
     $("body").addClass("loading").find(".modal").fadeIn(500)
   },
   ajaxStop: function() {
     $("body").removeClass("loading").find(".modal").finish().fadeOut(500)
   }
 }).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({url:"", method:"HEAD"})
 });
```

```js
$(document).on({
   ajaxStart: function() {
     $("body").addClass("loading").find(".modal").fadeIn(500)
   },
   ajaxStop: function() {
     $("body").removeClass("loading").find(".modal").finish().fadeOut(500)
   }
 }).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({url:"http://lorempixel.com/0/0/", method:"HEAD"})
 });
```

```css
.modal {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">modal</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't know why, but it's not working on [my page](http://www.raphaellechner.com/). And it's also just fading in the modal at the beginning, so there is no ajax right? Whats the whole point of the tutorial I posted at the beginning then?

Comment: @RaphaelLechner Content within `.modal` at http://www.raphaellechner.com/ appear to be comment node `<!-- Place at bottom of page -->` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no need for content inside the modal-div. Everything else is is added through css. I just need the "loading" class to be added to the body of the page when the page is loading.