# How to display the datatable with loading symbol using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to display the data table with a loading symbol.

I have more than 10,000 records. I need to display this records in data table. This is the code to display the record in data table ,

```
$('#example').dataTable({
         "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "loading......"
        }
    });
```

I have more than 10,000 records so that the data table displays a few seconds late. As a result I need to display the loading symbol. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery "Please Wait, Loading..." animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You must use Ajax (here is the example: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest_php )

The loading symbol you can get by jQuery Lazy ( http://plugins.jquery.com/lazy/ )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace "loading......" string with an image

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='loading.gif'>"
        }
    } );
```

Comment: ok tell me error plz ? Do u correctly insert the path of loading image ?

Comment: DataTable is undefined

Comment: $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='http://www.eurocopter.in/contest/images/loader33.gif'>"
        }
    } );

Comment: Can u please show me your Html as well if possible show me in  jsfiddle.net

Comment: There is no gif file present over there http://eurocopter.in/contest/images/loader33.gif

. Please check DataTable spelling as well . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

In Jquery :-

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').dataTable({
    });
     $('#example').show();

    });

In Html :-
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display:none">
```