# How to add a preloader when you click on a "a href"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Because on iPad I've tried to add :hover :active and :focus over some "a href" and there was not showing any effect, I've decided to add a preloader over page when the page is loading after your click. Can anyone explain to me how to add this preloader onclick;

```
$("#preloader").hide();
document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation) can help you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
     $("#yourID").on("click",function(){
         $("#preloader").show();
     });
});
```

and for hiding use either `$("#preloader").hide();` or

```
document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = 'none';
```

you don't have to use both.