# Adding text to a jquery wait animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code, which I found at: [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation), and successfully implemented.

Now, I'd like to display text right above the image. It can be many different messages. Can that be done?

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 )
                    url('images/spinner.gif')
                    50% 50% 
                    no-repeat;
}

body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $body.addClass("loading");
    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
        $body.removeClass("loading");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible way...

Modify your jQuery

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $body.addClass("loading");
        $('.modal').attr("data-message","I'm a message!");
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

Add this to your CSS

```
.modal:before {
    content: attr(data-message);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/6440/)

---

**EDIT**

> It can be many different messages.

As in selected from an array? ...

```
var messageArray = ["I'm a message", "Hello", "Lorem Ipsum"];

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $body.addClass("loading");
        $('.modal').attr("data-message",messageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * messageArray.length)]);
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/6441/)