# Show waiting animation during action redirect mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is some button which user clicks to be redirected to diffrent controller action. I would like to show user some nice waiting information (maybe using bootstrap?) that user knows to wait. Can you advice something? Below my curernt code:

this is part of my JS which is pasting some href url to modal bootstrap window:

```
...
  var href = $('#details').attr('href'); // currently returns '/TransportGallery/Details/1'
            href = href.slice(0, href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + id;
            $('#details').attr('href', href);
...
```

this is the modal bootstrap window where above js href will be placed and will replace this one:

```
...

                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "TransportGallery", New With {.id = 1})" class="btn btn-primary" id="details">
                    Show pictures
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-off" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Now when this is done there is some operation behind which is loading pictures to gallery and on that moment i would like to show user animation. How do do that?

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BlockUI.JS](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#details').on('click',function(){
      $.blockUI();
    });
 });
```

after you redirect page to somewhere else page will be automaticly unblockui.