# jQuery - Show loading message while using replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a PPT in a div while using replaceWith with google docs like this:

```js
$("#u1").click(function() {
  $(".cuerpo").replaceWith('<div class="cuerpo">' + '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://**************.pptx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"> </iframe>' + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that it take a few seconds to load completely and I need to display some message that the div is loading, is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery loaded callback method like this:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
   // Iframe has been loaded...Do whatever you want.

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already answered to a question similar to this, checkout [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery), this will probably help you with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new hidden div, for example:

`<div id="loadingDiv" style="display: none; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.8><img src="[image here if you want one]></div>`

Then before

`$( ".cuerpo" ).replaceWith( '<div class="cuerpo">' + '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://**************.pptx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>' + "</div>" );});`

add an additional line, like: `$('#loadingDiv').css("display","inherit");`

Don't forget to hide it again after content is loaded.

... That's at least one way to do it.