# Add JavaScript on form submit

Tags: javascript

I would like to add [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/72tkyn40/) to my site when my form is submitted because it could take long to submit. I would like the loading element to appear in the middle of the screen with a blurred background.

```
<form method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: You will probably have to add some more code showing what you have attempted to achieve this yourself, please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [*How can I create a “Please Wait, Loading…” animation using jQuery?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery) Ok, it uses jQuery, but the POJS technique is the same: intercept form submission, display animation, dialogue, whatever, then use a very short *setTimeout* to submit form.