# Jquery/Ajax loader's time to depend on page's loading time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mockjax

**Situation:**

I am looking for a jquery/ajax loader and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery/1964871#1964871) helpful.
Now I am using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpDUG/4952/) as my loader.
Everything works fine but I only have one concern.

Below the js code, 'responseTime' is fixed to 2.5 secs.

```
$.mockjax({ url: "/mockjax", responseTime: 2500 });
```

So if my page loads more than 5 secs, the loader only runs at 2.5 secs.

**Question:**

How am I going to depend the loader's time to my page's unpredictable loading time?


Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the mockjax code on your production site.

Comment: ok sir. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I'm looking for from [this site](http://blog.oio.de/2010/11/08/how-to-create-a-loading-animation-spinner-using-jquery/).


Below is the code I use.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
 
    $('#button-upload').click(function() {
        $('#spinner').show();
    });
 });
```

```css
.spinner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1234;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 102px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <img id="img-spinner" src="http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif" alt="Loading"/>
</div>


<input type = "submit" value = "Upload" id="button-upload" />
```

The loader is indefinite in this snippet, but it runs perfectly on my site.

Thanks guys for the help anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

You can show loader gif until window loads completely by

```
$(window).load(function(){

}
```

And do it like:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#cover').fadeOut(1000); 
});
```

```css
#cover {
    background: url("http://www.aveva.com/Images/ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat scroll center center #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cover"></div>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lklDJ5VRQao/maxresdefault.jpg" />
```

It will start with showing gif and will be faded out once content gets loaded completely.

Comment: I tried your code but found out the loader only works when my PHP/SQL script behind are done. I'm looking for something that when my script starts to run, the loader also starts and ends as the script ends.

Comment: Are you trying to show loader gif during some ajax call or until a webpage loads completely ?