# How to add text above spinning gif during Ajax call/HTML blocking

Tags: ajax, html, css

I found an excellent solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/how-can-i-create-a-please-wait-loading-animation-using-jquery) to add a spinning GIF during a long (8-12sec) Ajax call, but I can't figure out how to vertically centre some text just above the  GIF that will remain in the same relative position no matter the screen size.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<style>
    /* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
       Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
       with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
       for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
       our animation centered, and no-repeating */
    .modalLoading {
        display:    none;
        position:   fixed;
        z-index:    1000;
        top:        0;
        left:       0;
        height:     100%;
        width:      100%;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                    /*url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') */
                    url('<?php echo BASE_HDR_TAG . "contest/common/img/ajax-loader-red.gif"; ?>')
                    50% 50% 
                    no-repeat;
    }

    /* When the body has the loading class, we turn
       the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
    body.loading .modalLoading {
        overflow: hidden;   
    }

    /* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
       modal element will be visible */
    body.loading .modalLoading {
        display: block;
    }
    .modalFont {
        color:#8B0000;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight:900;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

</style>
```

This DIV is at the bottom of my body section:

```
<div class="modalLoading">
    <div style="margin-top:25px">           
        <span class="modalFont">Please wait while we generate your entry form, including the PDF copy.<br />
        Do not click the back button or close this browser tab.</span>            
    </div>
</div>
```

What it looks like now:
[image]

What I want it to look like:
[image]

**EDIT**
Trying the code from doesn't yield the desired results.

```
    /* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
       Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
       with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
       for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
       our animation centered, and no-repeating */
    .modalLoading {
        display:    none; /* if this is set to 'Flex' then the modal blocking appears on page refresh */
        position:   fixed;
        /*z-index:    1000;*/
        top:        0;
        right:      0;
        bottom:     0;
        left:       0;
        /*height:     100%;
        width:      100%;*/
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                    /*url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') */
                    url('<?php echo BASE_HDR_TAG . "contest/common/img/ajax-loader-red.gif"; ?>')
                    50% 50% 
                    no-repeat;
    }

    /* When the body has the loading class, we turn
       the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
    body.loading .modalLoading {
        overflow: hidden;   
    }

    /* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
       modal element will be visible */
    body.loading .modalLoading {
        display: block;
    }

    .modalFont {
        color:#8B0000;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight:900;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

<div class="modalLoading">         
    <span class="modalFont">Please wait while we generate your entry form, including the PDF copy.<br />
    Do not click the back button or close this browser tab.</span>            
</div>
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**
        /* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
           Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
           with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
           for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
           our animation centered, and no-repeating */
        .modalLoading {
            display:    flex;
            position:   fixed;
            /*z-index:    1000;*/
            top:        0;
            right:      0;
            bottom:     0;
            left:       0;
            /*height:     100%;
            width:      100%;*/
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                        /*url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') */
                        url('')
                        50% 50% 
                        no-repeat;
        }

```
    /* When the body has the loading class, we turn
       the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
    body.loading .modalLoading {
        overflow: hidden;   
    }

    /* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
       modal element will be visible */
    body.loading .modalLoading {
        display: flex;
    }

    .modalFont {
        color:#8B0000;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight:900;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center vertically a text, a possible solution is to use flexbox. 
With this HTML:

```
<div class="modalLoading">

        <span class="modalFont">Please wait while we generate your entry form, including the PDF copy.<br />
        Do not click the back button or close this browser tab.</span>            

</div>
```

You can write this CSS:

```
.modalLoading{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif')  50% 50% no-repeat;

}

.modalFont{
    margin-top: 100px; /* margin to move the text a little lower than gif loader. Change this margin with -100px if you want it to appear above the gif */
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

To work only after AJAX call, I only edited CSS the previous HTML I wrote doesn't change:

```
.modalLoading {
        display:    none; /* hidden when refresh the page */
        position:   fixed;
        z-index:    1000;
        top:        0;
        right:      0;
        bottom:     0;
        left:       0;

        /*height:     100%;
        width:      100%;*/
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
                    50% 50% 
                    no-repeat;
    }


    body.loading .modalLoading {
        overflow: hidden;   
    }


    body.loading .modalLoading {
        display: flex; /*display using Flexbox */
    }

    .modalFont{
    margin-top: 100px; /* margin to move the text a little lower than gif loader. Change this margin with -100px if you want it to appear above the gif */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. By changing display to flex, the modal blocking shows when I refresh the page, and not just when an Ajax call is invoked from my JS. Also, the text is not centered horizontally or vertically. I edited my question to show the result.

Comment: Have you tried  to change   `body.loading .modalLoading {display: block; }` in `body.loading .modalLoading {display: flex; }`?

Comment: I did, and now the text is centered correctly, but it still shows up when refreshing the page and **NOT** just when an Ajax call is made.

Comment: Indeed it does! What's different in that demo compared to what you have above? I can't mark yours as the answer unless it's updated.