# Display Animation on page load

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i followed following answer,

> [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964871/10697521][1]

and my animation is working fine, but in given example image is used to show animation,

insted of image, i want to show  following css animation in center on page load,

**Animation css, jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mattii/4k7L5vj1/1/

**Code:**

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
  <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
  <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
  <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
  <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
  <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.modal {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  animation: sk-chase 2.5s infinite linear both;
}

.sk-chase-dot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  animation: sk-chase-dot 2.0s infinite ease-in-out both; 
}

.sk-chase-dot:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-chase-dot-before 2.0s infinite ease-in-out both; 
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: -1.1s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: -1.0s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: -0.9s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: -0.8s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: -0.7s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: -0.6s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(1):before { animation-delay: -1.1s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(2):before { animation-delay: -1.0s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(3):before { animation-delay: -0.9s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(4):before { animation-delay: -0.8s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(5):before { animation-delay: -0.7s; }
.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(6):before { animation-delay: -0.6s; }

@keyframes sk-chase {
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}

@keyframes sk-chase-dot {
  80%, 100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}

@keyframes sk-chase-dot-before {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.4); 
  } 100%, 0% {
    transform: scale(1.0); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so show that animation. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Justinas nothing wrong, animation has 8 kb size so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these css into .modal class then enjoy it! :)

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

New css:

```
.modal {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  animation: sk-chase 2.5s infinite linear both;
}
```