# How to display Progress message?

Tags: android

After login button click I am waiting for the webservice response. At that time I need to display a progress message after receiving response I have to close that message. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a hidden div tag with a loading gif image that you set to visible when you are waiting and again set to set invisible after that.

You may find the answer you're looking for starting here:
[With jQuery, how can I implement a "page loading" animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750358/with-jquery-how-can-i-implement-a-page-loading-animation)

Follow the link inside. Good luck.