# Loading or getting ready message

Tags: javascript, dom

i have some web based application that creates a zip file when user asks for it. and it takes around 5 sec of time which is uncertain.. so i want to show him a loading sceen which should **disable my main screen** for the time being and show loading oo processing animation something..

i am using jsp servlets

Update: i dont want to use jQuery

Edit: implemented using jQuery but want to do the same without it

thanks.

Comment: What if i want this using javascript only and no jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to lock browser screen and show [loading process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750358/with-jquery-how-can-i-implement-a-page-loading-animation). You could use ajax to make requests and receive responses asynchronously.

Why use jQuery?

- It uses KISS principle - Keep It Simple Stupid
- It has very good documentation and tutorials
- The community is very active, helpful, and warm
- The core file’s packed size is small
- It deploys almost use-at-will approach
- It has strong logic and workflow and is easily extensible

Since you do not want to use jQuery you have to deal with javascript basics like manipulating the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Basic ajax tutorial:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro1.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro3/

This tutorials are on DOM manipulation:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro4/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro5/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro6/

Comment: why not use jQuery? It gives you powerful methods performing ajax operations

Comment: @ArtWorAD - i understand your love for jQuery but my project says a big no for jQuery :(
even i am very excited to learn jQuery.. will also appreciate if i can get any good tutorial link for jquery

Comment: well then you need to deal with DOM manipulation, i update my answer; also you should update your question that you do not want to use jQuery